# Get Value from Textbox and Lookup using AJAX

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

So right now i'm developing some software payroll project, and right now i'm stuck with this kind of problem [[*CLICK HERE FOR THE PIC*] The example code for what i'm doing(Razor)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpO2N.png)

```all
<td style="padding-right:10px;">
                            @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBoxFor(model => model.Cycle)
                                    .ID("txtDay")
                                    .Width(100)
                            )
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @(Html.DevExtreme().LookupFor(model => model.WorkingShiftId)
                                    .ID("lookupWorkingShiftId")
                                    .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
                                    .Controller("WorkingShiftAPI")
                                    .LoadAction("GetAllWorkingShift")
                                    .Key("id")
                                    )
                                    .ValueExpr("id")
                                    .DisplayExpr("name")
                                    .Width(290)
                            )
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left:20px;">
                            @(Html.DevExtreme().Button()
                                .ID("btnGenerate")
                                .Type(ButtonType.Default)
                                .Text("Generate")
                                .OnClick("btnGenerate_OnClick")
                                //.Hint("Generate")
                            //.UseSubmitBehavior(true)
                            )
                        </td>
```

so what i want to do, is to get the value from the Textbox and the Lookup, and the Generate button for the trigger

*#PS, currently in this project i'm using DevExtreme in Visual Studio and  ASP.NET Core 2.0*

***UPDATE HERE PLEASE CHECK THE PIC***

[[*HERE FOR THE PIC*]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcrGn.png)

```all
function btnGenerate_OnClick(data) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("getCycleResult", "WorkingPattern")';

    var Cycle = $("#txtDay").dxTextBox("instance");
    Cycle.option("value", data.Cycle);

    var WorkingShiftId = $("#lookupWorkingShiftId").dxLookup("instance");
    WorkingShiftId.option("value", data.WorkingShiftId);


    var confirmGenerate = true;
    if (confirmGenerate == true) {
        @*urlString = '@Url.Action("getCycleResult", "WorkingPattern")';*@

        $.ajax({
            url: url, // '@Url.Action("getCycleResult", "WorkingPattern")'
            type: 'GET',
            data: { Cycle, WorkingShiftId },


            success: function (data) {

                alert("in");

                var dataWorkingPattern = $("#gridWorkingPattern").dxDataGrid({
                    dataSource: data,
                    columns: ["cycle","workingShiftId"]

                });

            }

        })

    }

}
```

So to make that happen i'm using AJAX to take the value from the Textbox and Lookup

```c#
[HttpGet]
    public List<WorkingPatternDetail> getCycleResult(int Cycle, Guid WorkingShiftId)
    {
        List<WorkingPatternDetail> oWorkingPatternDetailList = new List<WorkingPatternDetail>();

        for (var i = 1; i < Cycle+1; i++)
        {
            WorkingPatternDetail oWorkingPatternDetail = new WorkingPatternDetail();
            oWorkingPatternDetail.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            oWorkingPatternDetail.Cycle = i;
            oWorkingPatternDetail.WorkingShiftId = WorkingShiftId;
            oWorkingPatternDetailList.Add(oWorkingPatternDetail);
        }


        return oWorkingPatternDetailList ;
    }
```

and this the Controller after getting the value, (LOOPING) the value, and after that, i take the result and show the result in the #gridWorkingPattern (in the AJAX), (sorry about my english,  and i'm new here)

***UPDATE***

I was trying to get the value from the **Textbox** and the **Lookup** but unfortunately the value doesn't get into the function, i can't even get the _**btnGenerate_onClick**_ function to work

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the instance of the dx control which is in your case something like this:

```
var txtDay = $("#txtDay").dxTextBox().dxTextBox("instance");
var workingShift = $("#lookupWorkingShiftId").dxLookup().dxLookup("instance");
```

You than access values like this:

```
var day = txtDay.option("value");
var shiftId = workingShift.option("value");
```

Comment: **Woah**, it works ! Thanks sir Rob ! but can you explain why my code doesn't works in that way....`var Cycle = $("#txtDay").dxTextBox("instance");
    Cycle.option("value", data.Cycle);

    var WorkingShiftId = $("#lookupWorkingShiftId").dxLookup("instance");
    WorkingShiftId.option("value", data.WorkingShiftId);`

Comment: $("#txtDay") is a jQUery selector. Than calling dxTextBox() on this actually builds the control and finally calling dxTextBox("instance") returns isntance of Devextreme object that is dxTextBox. In your example you are doing $("#txtDay").dxTextBox("instance") when it should really be $("txtDay").dxTextBox().dxTextBox("instance")